# Magento 2 Error while working

Tags: php, mysql, magento, amazon-web-services, zend-framework

While working on Magento 2.1.0  Getting this error cannot find solution for this.

[image]

Sometime giving permission `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/magento/public_html/subdirectory` to the folder then its working fine. 
My store hosted in Amazon web server how to resolve this issue permanently?

What kind of error is it related to Amazon web server or Magento 2.1.0?